# Repaint() not being called in Thread

Tags: java, swing

I have a jFrame that is implementing a poker game. I have a thread so that the computer opponents take time with their moves. I've tried to implement it so that the Thread waits when a human turn comes up. Before I even put a human player in, though, the frame doesn't call `repaint()`. I've used the debugger in Netbeans to check this: it does get to the line where the frame calls `repaint()`, but for some reason it doesn't actually do it. Here's the code:

```
public void run() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < players.size(); j++) {
            Card card = deck.draw();
            players.get(i).addToHand(card);
            output.append("Player " + players.get(i).getName() + " got a " + card + ".\n");
            System.out.println("Player " + players.get(i).getName() + " got a " + card + ".\n");
        }
    }

    while (true) {

        if (!players.isEmpty() && players.get(0) instanceof HumanPlayer)
            humansTurn = true;

        if (humansTurn) {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        } else if (humanMoveMade) {
            playMove(humanMove, players.remove(0));
            humanMoveMade = false;
        }else {
            //unrelated code, then:

            debug.update();

            repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically it's supposed to get to that `else` whenever the human player isn't making his or her move, and it does get to that `repaint`, but it never goes through for some reason. The window appears, but none of the components.

EDIT: I should also mention that the `debug.update()` method call before the `repaint()` is supposed to update information on another frame, but nothing is showing up in that window either...

I need to have this ready soon, so I really need some help with this. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh...sorry, false alarm. I had forgotten to check when this frame gets created. Turns out I had accidentally called the `run()` method instead of running the thread the way it normally is (I had tried to implement something different beforehand). After going back to making a new thread and calling `start()`, it works now.